# Combining multiple Google sheets into single Google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have multiple google sheets (45 of them, all dynamic, its content will keep on changing) and I want to combine data of all of them into a single file. I was hoping to use some `importrange` or `QUERY` function so that moment one / any file is updated, the changes reflect automatically on the combined sheet.

Example book 1 :

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sOkV9BT8ptndE0xcN2MUi4tTZ5p-aZxuLY_u29Y6nBI/edit?usp=sharing

Example book 2 :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jZml9oVI2Flma407AB4ndl_ZIsQ_5I8zhkzvbL_EO_g/edit?usp=sharing

Example combined book : 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LkiIY1aUmwaouR7f4KhaGs6MV365KY7DYUPMiTzxjvc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

- first you need to connect them by pasting each `IMPORTRANGE` formula in some cell to get `#REF!` error
- then hover over that `#REF!` error with your cursor and a secret magic button will popup
- click on it to **allow access**
  then you can stack up all import ranges and wrap them in a query:

---

```
=QUERY(
 {IMPORTRANGE("ID1-or-URL1", "Sheet1!A1:A"); 
  IMPORTRANGE("ID2-or-URL2", "Sheet1!A1:A");
  IMPORTRANGE("ID3-or-URL3", "Sheet1!A1:A");
  IMPORTRANGE("ID4-or-URL4", "Sheet1!A1:A")}, 
 "where Col1 is not null"), 0)
```

---

**update:**

```
={       IMPORTRANGE("1sOkV9BT8ptndE0xcN2MUi4tTZ5p-aZxuLY_u29Y6nBI", "Sheet1!A1:N2"); 
  QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1sOkV9BT8ptndE0xcN2MUi4tTZ5p-aZxuLY_u29Y6nBI", "Sheet1!A3:N" ); 
         IMPORTRANGE("19SFnJab9xVW2SenK-8IuG2cQRT2exJeyqARjTdDE_R8", "Sheet1!A3:N" )}, 
  "where Col1 is not null", 0)}
```

Comment: Hello, I tried to use this for two files with following command : =QUERY({importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1notshowingforprivacyg/edit#gid=589555774","Activity Tracker!A3:n3000");importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1notshowingdetailsforprivacyw/edit#gid=0","Activity Tracker!A3:n3000")},"where Col1 is not null",0) i am getting error as Error
In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows. However I copy same path twice i am able to read it (same data twice basically).

Comment: i do need help. :( i am able to read same spreadsheet twice but reading two different files i am getting error as  Error In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

Comment: =QUERY({importrange("File1","Activity Tracker!A3:n3000");importrange("File1","Activity Tracker!A3:n3000")},"where Col1 is not null",0) works (same file read twice) but =QUERY({importrange("File1","Activity Tracker!A3:n3000");importrange("File2","Activity Tracker!A3:n3000")},"where Col1 is not null",0) (trying to read File1 and File 2) error as Error In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.

Comment: try to not lock down the **N** - `Tracker!A3:N`

Comment: sorry same observation... for some reason it do not like different files.

Comment: can you share a copy of that sheet?

Comment: i modified it but you can reproduce results https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19SFnJab9xVW2SenK-8IuG2cQRT2exJeyqARjTdDE_R8/edit#gid=0    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1sOkV9BT8ptndE0xcN2MUi4tTZ5p-aZxuLY_u29Y6nBI/edit#gid=0

Comment: try something like this: `={IMPORTRANGE("1sOkV9BT8ptndE0xcN2MUi4tTZ5p-aZxuLY_u29Y6nBI", "Sheet1!A1:N2");
 QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("1sOkV9BT8ptndE0xcN2MUi4tTZ5p-aZxuLY_u29Y6nBI", "Sheet1!A3:N");
        IMPORTRANGE("19SFnJab9xVW2SenK-8IuG2cQRT2exJeyqARjTdDE_R8", "Sheet1!A3:N")},
 "select * where Col1 is not null", 0)}`

Comment: @SurendraGaikwad answer updated and here is demo sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12mJAWSgE_lwt1LFLdM9qFi5-Mzsm48zPF0wKu_KniDY/edit#gid=2139234355